# How can I update yum list of available MySQL packages?

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, yum

I have MySQL 5.6 installed on cent os. I am trying to update it to 5.7, but yum packages contain only mysql57-community-dmr version, not mysql57-community, seems like my list of packages is outdated, is there any way to update it?

Answer (score 0):

First, check that you have the MySQL repo enabled:

```
yum repolist enabled | grep "mysql.*-community.*"
```

Then do this:

```
yum clean all
```

and then re-check for updates using yum.